# CodeIgniter load class into class

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have start working with CodeIgniter, but i can't understand one think. How do i load one class into another?

```
$this->load->library("hello_world");
```

This is not working?

my class -> load -> hello_world class

```
class myclass {
      function test() {
         $this->load->library("hello_world");
         $this->hello_world->hello();
      }
}
```

Message: Undefined property: myclass::$load

Comment: where do you saved your class? in application/library ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to load a class depends on the load->library function being available. It is made available to the controller and model classes, but extending these may not be appropriate for your use.

Instead you can either get a reference to CI and use that to load and refer to your class, or you can load it as usual in PHP ($c = new MyClass).

To get a rerence to CI use the following:

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->load->library('session');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the CI controller/model

e.g.

```
class Some_controller extends Controller
{
    public function index() {}
}
```

Comment: That is actualy for controllers and not for librarys. I think he is asking how to include a library?